# jQuery: Removing duplicate elements - temporarily

Tags: javascript, jquery, duplicates

I have a list of elements with a common class and want to hide all of the duplicates. I can achieve this. However, I have a "toggle" link which shows and hides the list of elements. When the toggle occurs I want the browser to "reset" or "forget" what has been marked as a duplicate, ready for the user to click filter again.

My [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/c6Tbp/) shows the filter working but I don't want to change every child DIV of `#container` into a visible element as line 19 is doing for example - this is occurring outside this code in my project already. To "forget" the element I need to use something like what's on line 18, although this doesn't seem to work.

Preferably, the "forgetting" would occur as soon as the element is hidden (line 7), so it is ready to appear again in a future instance of the filter. What would be the correct syntax?

EDIT: for a better idea of what I'm after:

1. Go to http://www.adaptworkbench.co.uk/
2. On the left hand side click on the "Securities" checkbox. You will see "TEST JOB" appear. Uncheck the box.
3. On the left hand side click on the "Secretarial" checkbox. You will see "TEST JOB" appear. Uncheck the box.
4. Click "Securities" again. After all is said and done "TEST JOB" will NOT appear but I want the browser to "forget" it was marked as "SEEN" and show it.

The point of this is so that a duplicate entry will not appear if two checkboxes are checked - if you tick both "Securities" and "Secretarial" you can see this is working, but I want it to FORGET right after hiding the duplicate so that "TEST JOB" will appear again when clicking just one checkbox afterwards.

Hope this makes sense!

Comment: I'm not understanding what you're wanting... I uncomment your `seen[txt] = false` and it hides and shows just fine.

Comment: Thanks for taking a look - please see my edit above.

Answer (score 1):

Once you've selected all of those elements, you could hide them by adding a special class that only they can have, like `tempHidden` or something. Then once you're ready to show them again, you can select all items that have that "special" class:

```
$('.tempHidden').hide();
```

and when you're ready to show them again

```
$('.tempHidden').show();
```

and whenever you need to select everything except the hidden items, you can use the `.not()` method:

```
$('.everything').not('.tempHidden');
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment, maybe I haven't been specific enough - please see my edit in original post.

Comment: in that case, you can perform an `$('.someCheckBox').on('change', function() {})` and just show and hide blocks depending on which things have been clicked and what their current checked state is.

Answer (score 0):

UPDATED BASED ON REQUIREMENTS IN COMMENTS BELOW (last one was broke this isn't):

Basically using the same `id` for each job allows us to track the job, and we can assign multiple classes for check type of job.  There are probably multiple was to do this, and probably depend more on how your actually displaying them, but this works.

http://jsfiddle.net/EVDQa/6/

HTML:

```
<div id="input">
    <form>
        <input type="checkbox" name="jobs" value="security">Security
        <br>
        <input type="checkbox" name="jobs" value="secretarial">Secretarial
    </form>
</div>
<div id="display">
    <div class="posting hidden security" id="12345">
         This is a test Security job. Id: 12345
    </div>
    <div class="posting hidden secretarial" id="12345">
         This is a test Secretarial job. Id: 12345
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.posting {
    border: 2px solid #000000;
}
.hidden {
    display: none;
    visibility: hidden;
}
#input {
    float: left;
}
#display {
    margin-left: 100px;
    float: left;
}
```

JS:

```
$("#input form input").change(function () {
    var jobType = $(this).val();
    var jobIds = [];
    var id;

    function getJobs() {
        $(".posting." + jobType).each(function () {
            id = $(this).attr("id");
            if ($.inArray(id, jobIds) === -1) {
                jobIds.push(id);
                $(this).toggleClass("hidden");

                if ($(this).hasClass("hidden")) {
                    jobIds = jQuery.grep(jobIds, function (value) {
                        return value != id;
                    });
                }
            }
        });
    }

    $(".posting:not(.hidden, ." + jobType + ")").each(function () {
        id = $(this).attr("id");
        if ($.inArray(id, jobIds) === -1) {
            jobIds.push(id);
        }
    });

    //Toggle jobs
    getJobs();
    jobType = $(":checked").val();
    getJobs();
});
```

Comment: Thanks for posting - it would need to be the case that clicking one checkbox shows one job, and checking both checkboxes also shows only one job - so only one job is shown when both boxes are checked. Do you see what I mean?

Comment: Which job should be visible when both are checked?  Do you need to be able to page through multiples only showing one at a time? Or do you mean that both jobs are technically the same job, it's just considered both a security and secretarial job?

Comment: Yes exactly - it is one job that belongs to both Security and Secretarial, I just don't want it to show up twice. I would have thought by setting `seen[txt] = false` as soon as the DIV is hidden it would be displayed again next time around? Something tells me it's only a line or two of code that I'm missing.

Comment: @Chris Okay this one does completely work.  The last one had an issue with unhidding and hidding with different combonations of check marks.

Comment: Great many thanks, I will take a look at this later and get back to you.